# Edit several nested models in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following models in Django (simplified for readability):

```
class Test(models.Model):
    pass

class Page(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)

class Question(models.Model);
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

I would like to **fully** edit a test in the admin area, that is edit `Test` data, add `Page`s for that test, and in turn add `Question`s for each page and `Answer`s for each question.
What is the easiest and Django-ish mode of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from project.apps.models import Test, Page,Question, Answer

class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Answer
extra = 0

class QuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Question
extra = 0

class PageInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Page
extra = 0

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display =('__unicode__','item1','item2')
search_fields = ('field1','field2')
inlines=[AnswersItemInline,QuestionsItemInline,PageItemInline]

admin.site.register(Test,TestAdmin)
```

Comment: In your example, I would need foreign keys in order to be able to include `Question`s and `Answer`s as inlines to `Test`.

Comment: the inlines=[] in TestAdmin will do it . if i understand what you want, you can ignore search_fields

Comment: No, I mean that I cannot include `QuestionInline` and `AnswerInline` in `TestAdmin` `inlines=[]` because a foreign key that should link these models is missing. Here is the exception that occurs: `<class 'tests.models.Answer'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'tests.models.Test'>`

Comment: ok, i see now, the relation should only between Test and Page first, and the rest going to be other nesting.